# Subtract a row value from the mean of the corresponding column and then sum the differences together

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

Here is a reproducible problem set-

```
c = c(1,2,3,4)
d = c(4,1,2,4)
e = c(2,1,5,4)
f = c(2,3,3,4)
tdf <- data.frame(c,d,e,f)
```

I can't figure out how I can subtract each row value from the mean of the corresponding column and then sum all these differences together for each column and save them.

basically I want to compute summation(xi-xavg) for each column. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: `sweep(tdf, 2, STATS=colMeans(tdf))` ... and then `colSums()`; it produces a 0 for every column.

Comment: sweep function does the job beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

The `apply()` family of functions will solve this issue. `sapply` will apply a function to each column of a data.frame and return the results of the function. So simply pass it a data frame and define a function you want performed

```
sapply(tdf, function(x) sum(x-mean(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to replicate the `colMeans` to get the dimensions same as that of the original data, get the difference and find the sum of each column with `colSums`

```
colSums(tdf - colMeans(tdf)[col(tdf)])
```

---

Or another option is to take the transpose of 'tdf', subtract from `colMeans` and then do the `rowSums`

```
rowSums(t(tdf) - colMeans(tdf))
```